# how to redirect the page with data through codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, redirect

```
$data['family_info'] = $this->Registration->getFamilyDetails($student_id);
redirect("Application/studentRegistration/".$student_id,$data);
$this->load->view("Application/familyInfo/".$student_id);
```

i would like to redirect the controller with some data as mysql recordset but when im trying with redirect - its now giving back the data,
while trying to view function i can but i unable to send student id as a query string.

**CI/index.php/Application/familyInfo/182**

unbale to get data to this page and using redirect.
using view i can get the data but unable to get the querystring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will leave control after you redirect the page.

Loading view after redirection does not work.

What you can do is: you are already in sending us through redirection.

After redirection, on the destination page,  get data depending upon passed id.

Answer (score 0):

You only can pass the **id** only from redirect but not the data as `$this->load->view`, to get back the data just simply do like this:

```
public function studentRegistration($student_id)
{
    $data['family_info'] = $this->Registration->getFamilyDetails($student_id);
    $this->load->view('Application/studentRegistration/'.$student_id,$data);
}
```

Comment: when i trying the above statments, I'm getting error like, **error page not found. Application/familyInfo/182.php** help out Imran